# Why do I have 2 waveforms with wavesurfer.js when playing?

Tags: javascript, audiocontext, wavesurfer.js

I have:

```
this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: "#wavesurfer-player",
        height: 50,
        audioContext: _.get(this.$store, "state.audioContext.context"),
        waveColor: "blue",
        progressColor: "red"
      });
      this.wavesurfer.on("loading", progress => {
        this.loadingProgress = progress;
      });
      this.wavesurfer.load(this.url);

      this.wavesurfer.on("ready", () => {
        this.loadingProgress = 100;
        this.wavesurfer.un("ready");
      });
```

This works out well:
[image]

But when I play, another waveform is shown:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting them both to the same color seems to have solved this:

```
        waveColor: "blue",
        progressColor: "red"
```